# Using openssl with C#

Tags: c#, windows, openssl

I am attempting to do this challenge: https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/7 and I am having some trouble working with the openssl.net library found here: http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/

I have had a look through the standard OpenSSL documentation and the bit of documentation available for the openssl.net library and I have been unable to figure out how to use the Openssl Ciphers functionality as described in the challenge ("Easiest way: use OpenSSL::Cipher and give it AES-128-ECB as the cipher.")

Does anyone know of a similar library with more documentation that I might be able to work with or can someone give me an example of the OpenSSL::Cipher encrypt or decrypt function to get me started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need OpenSsl for that simple problem. .NET libraries are more than enough:

```
using (var aes = new AesManaged())
{
    byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("YELLOW SUBMARINE");
    aes.Key = key;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

    string b64 = File.ReadAllText("7.txt");
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);

    using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor())
    {
        byte[] result = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
    }
}
```

Note that normally I try not to use the `Encoding.ASCII` (and I prefer to use `Encoding.UTF8`), because in this world few things are really ASCII... But this problems seems to be one of those :-)

Comment: Sould I use openssl as a third party lib for Sni implementation in my c# webserver? Do you have any idea? I've read a lot and found schannel windows api which has very poor documentation, specially for sni implementation